# Count number of row results for a row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How do I group/filter rows and then get total rows for each column. I am going to diagram what the result should be. I don't want to show the actual data. Just the count per column

Out Put should look like this

```
        Column A      Column B      Column C
Row A - 235 records   300 records   15 records
Row B - 1 record      80 records    900 records
```

Each column represent a count on the same field but filtered.
So ..

```
Column A is really Count(MyColumn) WHERE = A
Column B is really Count(MyColumn) WHERE = B
```

To summarize each row is a grouping + filter and each column is a count based on the number of rows contained in that grouping. No row data needs to be displayed.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do the count in the SQL so that your dataset returns exactly what you want to show in the report?

Comment: I have to use the dataset in a wide away to tables on the report. Some using the same logic with a different filter. Plus the query is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a table in the group by using the following formula:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!MyColumn.Value = "A", 1, 0))
```

However, this type of summary report is what a [matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx) is designed to do. Use the Row field as the row group, the column field as the column group and a `Count` expression in the intersection and it will do it all for you.

Comment: I ended up using a matrix. I wanted the tablix so I could merge cells. Although I may play around with this soon.